# How to I tween an object to a top/left position on the page, relative to the viewport or body?

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap

I'm using the Greensock library, and their TweenLite function.

I'm trying to get the myTarget to tween/animate to a position relative to the viewport or body (or parent element, whatever), rather than relative to the element itself.

How can I do this?

When I run the following code, it Tweens the myTarget to a position relative to its own starting position.

```
TweenLite.to(myTarget, 0.5, { top: '200px', left: '200px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/wugeyi/1/edit?html,js,output)

pay attention to **position: relative** otherwise the **left** will not effect.

**CSS**

```
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #c9c;
  position: relative;

}
```

**JS**

```
var obj = $('div');
var width = $(window).width() - 100;
TweenMax.to(obj,3,{left: width});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with **GSAP**. IMHO, I think you are failing to understand the concept of `position` attribute of CSS.

In your case, I think your **parent** element needs to have `position: relative;` and your child element i.e. your `myTarget` needs to have `position: absolute;`.

Take a look at this quick [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/exv2pvwb/) to help you understand.

Also, please read [this thorough article](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) on understanding this **position** attribute available on CSS-Tricks.com.

Hope it helps.